# Unable to connect to WiFi via Win7 Desktop's internal or external USB Wireless NIC (can ping; no browser access); can use Android USB tethering

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

I have had this issue since I moved into my new sublease a few months ago. Effectively, I am unable to connect to my apartment's Comcast WiFi using my Windows 7 desktop's built in wireless card. I can see the SSID, the password authenticates, pinging sites like google.com or superuser.com works as does nslookup and tracert. What doesn't work is going into the browser through Firefox or Chrome and trying to visit a website. A connection is established, but pages never load.

Every other device I have can connect to the internet. I took advantage of this by using an old Android Device and using it to serve as a WiFi bridge using USB tethering. With that, I can easily get online and my speeds are reasonable.

I thought that this was indicative that I had a bad wireless adapter, but I don't think so for two reasons now:

1. I can connect to other, far-away networks using my built in adapter (even though their signals come and go).
2. A new USB network adapter I bought yesterday works on other devices but not on my desktop. It has the exact same issue as my built-in adapter.

I have Private Internet Access installed, but it never confounded anything before and it doesn't impact my connection if I use my Android Device.

What do you think the cause is, and do you think I can get around it? Is it possible that Comcast is blocking my machine for some reason?

Comment: Does it work with PIA disabled? Usually If ping works then its a DNS issue.

Comment: It does not work with PIA disabled, unfortunately. I actually uninstalled PIA entirely and tested it that way as well.

Further, things work fine with PIA disabled or enabled if using my wireless connection through Android's USB tethering to act as a surrogate for a WiFi card.

Comment: Try flushing the dns...http://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-flush-the-dns-cache-in-windows-7-vista-294

Comment: Do you have a manually configured DNS address? Can you get to your router's web interface?

Comment: I decided to try a shotgun tactic of doing everything possible at once. Thank you Moab for your suggestion.
ipconfig /flushdns -->net stop dnscache --> net start dnscache --> ipconfig /release --> ipconfig /renew --> netsh int ip reset reset.log --> netsh winsock reset catalog --> shutdown /r

Now I am back up and good to go! I swear I thought I had done these all before. Oh well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your Android device is authorized by Comcast you might be able to use USB tethering as it should avoid having to login on each device once.